# How to add parameters to request.form in Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, immutable-collections, authlib

How can I add an object like `{'client_id':'...', 'grant_type':'...'}` to `request.form` in Flask ?

I know `request.form` is [immutable](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.html), but I need to do this because the method I need to use (from [oauth](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/afa9e43544a3575b06d97df27971d5698152bbac/authlib/flask/oauth2/authorization_server.py#L263)) just accepts `request.form`, if I pass *.json* it doesn't work.

The documentation to this class it's not good. I did try to create an instance of `ImmutableMultiDict`, but I don't know how to set the dict to `ImmutableMultiDict` and then to `request.form` properly.

**Obs** : I can't send the arguments (Key:Value) in the request like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an intermediary route that accepts the object as json then use the python `requests` module to post it to the route that you are using oauth from.

Since the `requests` module can simulate making `POST` and `GET` requests, then everything should be sorted.